# How to handle If Data returning from $http.get() is not in JSON format, Its a normal Text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am using get API to request data from a specified resource.

```
$http.get('http:...').success(function() {

});
```

But I am getting error

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token r in JSON at position 1",

How we can handle this issue?

Comment: The `.success` method had been [deprecated and removed from AngularJS V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 0):

### Override the default response transformation of `JSON.parse`

If the Content-Type is `application/json` or the response looks like JSON, The $http service will deserialize it using a JSON parser.

To avoid that, configure the `transformResponse` property to pass the response without any transformation:

```
var config = { transformResponse: angular.identity };

$http.get(url, config).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service - Overriding the Default Transformations Per Request](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#overriding-the-default-transformations-per-request)

Answer (score 0):

[The `.success` and `.error` methods have been removed from AngularJS 1.6.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10508)

Instead of

```
$http.get(...)
  .success(function(data, ...) {
    ...
  })
  .error(function(data, ...) {
    ...
  });
```

use

```
$http.get(...).then(
  function success(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    ...   
},function error(response) {
    var data = response.data;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Json is the default, you can set the expected reponse type to `text`:

```
$http.get('http:...', {responseType: "text"}).success(function(reponse) {
    console.log(reponse);
});
```

More info can found in [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments)